# How to revert file in child branch which is checked in parent branch?

Tags: git, github, git-revert

Let's say I have branch structure like

- mater

  - child1
  - child2

I commited(Modified and deleted) some set of files in child1 and merged that in master. 
Now I want to revert only one deleted file from that commit list into child2 branch and keep master untouched it means it should remain deleted in master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Switch to child 2: `git checkout child2`
2. Checkout the file you want from the commit you want: `git checkout child1 files`

If `file` was deleted at the commit pointed to by `child1` and you want the state *before* that deletion, try `git checkout child1^ files`

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
1) git log --online
2)get SHA of previous commit, git checkout <SHA before commit>  (detached head state)
3)Copy contents of file that are untouched
4)paste somewhere untouched content
5)git checkout master
6)copy content of touched file
7)paste touched file into child2
8)paste untouched file in master
9)commit in both branches
```

Comment: So you mean in this case as I deleted files in master, I would have to recreate same in child2. But in that case git will treat it as new file and I will loose history.

Comment: You shouldn't lose anything, your current state is saved in your commits. My whole flow is about making new commits, you re checking into an older commit getting the data you need to recommit and then going back to your branch not erasing any history.